# How to formally prove this integral identity?

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I was doing some investiations into 'areas under curves' an found by a  geometric analogy the following integral identity:
 $$
\int_0^a f(x)dx =\frac12 \int_0^{f ′ (a)}   (a- f^{-1}(f′(x)))^2 dx
$$
Now im not sure whether this applies to all classes of functions, but it seems to work for polynominals. I am asking whether there is a field in math about such identities, and what it is called?

And how would one formally prove the identity?

Comment: Not sure it holds even for $f(x)=x$. $f'(x)=1$, $f^{-1}(x)=x$. I get $a^2/2=(a-1)^2/2$

Comment: Not sure about how this is expressed corrctly but by  $$ f^{-1}(f′(x)) $$ i mean the inverse function of the derivative, and for y=1+0x, it not as straightforward

Comment: What do you mean inverse function of the derivative?

Comment: For example $f(x)=x^3$   then $f'(x)=3x^2$ and  $f^{-1}(f′(x))= (\frac{x}3)^{\frac12}$